# facebook auto loggin

Tags: iphone, session, facebook

I want to save the login information of Facebook after closing the application.
So every time when user opens application, no need to login again.

Is done by saving the session object into a plist?
I'm using facebook connect.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the thing with face book connect try this if I understand it right :

```
if([session resume] == YES){
        shouldRedirectToPublish = NO;

    }   else {
        if(session == nil){
            session = [[FBSession sessionForApplication:@"private" secret:@"private" delegate:self]retain];
        }
        shouldRedirectToPublish = YES;



    }
```

The facebook connect does it for you you have to just call the [session resume] . see the facebook connect example carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Because it relies on the facebook cookie you won't be able to save it, at least that's my understanding.